# Least Energy Path, Contour Following, around Hills toward Goal

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, surfaces, heat-equation, gradient-flows

I have a matrix of elevation values which could be said represents $h(x,y)$. I can obtain contours using this function that are like sides of hills, and I have a starting point and an end point.

How do I create a path from initial point toward end point by a) remaining on the same elevation level as much as possible (less climbing) and b) move towards the goal at the same time.

I would like to do this by utilizing multivariable calculus as much as possible. Can I take the diagonal direction of the gradient for example and combine it with a "goal direction" somehow that would give me a direction at each step? Maybe this could be an instance of heat flow where hills are a "denser material" which takes longer to heat up and easier path is around them, more direct?

I've seen approaches that define potential functions which create repelling potential and attracting potential and come up with a direction that way.

I liked the mathematics of this approach, in my case however the mountains are not 100% obstacles. I am looking for a similar approach in terms of localness, use of functions though.

We can assume $h(x,y)$ is a smooth manifold, differentiable everywhere, the discrete representation of the function would simply be a matrix, and it would be great to hear about discrete methods to solve a proposed solution as well.

Note: I will keep some links I come across below.

Repel-attract method
http://portal.ku.edu.tr/~cbasdogan/Courses/Robotics/projects/algorithm_poten_field.pdf

Using the heat equation
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/HeatMethod/paper.pdf

Note: the final answer to this question will probably be [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301449/optimal-trajectory-through-elevation-field-ex-y-with-least-energy). This is more of a control theory problem.

Comment: Are we free to assume that $h(x,y)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Yes $h(x,y)$ is differentiable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gamma : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ is a level curve of $h$, then then $h \circ \gamma$ is constant, and therefore its derivative is $0$:
$$\frac {d(h\circ\gamma(t))}{dt} = \nabla h\cdot \dot \gamma(t) = 0$$

That is, the level curves always move perpendicular to the gradient. One such vector perpendicular to $\nabla h$ is $(h_y, -h_x)$. If we look at the flows of $(h_y, -h_x)$, then we have a set of level curves through every point. All other level curves are just reparameterizations $\gamma(g(t))$ for some $g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

---

In the discrete case, you estimate $h_x$ with $\Delta_x h = \dfrac{h(x + \Delta x,y) - h(x,y)}{\Delta x}$, and similarly for $\Delta_y h$. The horizontal direction is thus given by $h^\perp = (\Delta_y h, -\Delta_x h)$. But to control step size, it is helpful to normalize this (we only need a direction perpendicular to the gradient of $h$, not a particular vector). So, we define $$\hat h^\perp = \left(\frac{\Delta_y h}{\sqrt{\Delta_y h^2 + \Delta_x h^2}},\frac{-\Delta_x h}{\sqrt{\Delta_y h^2 + \Delta_x h^2}}\right)$$

Moving in this direction should be level. So if you start at $(x_0, y_0)$, and are moving with stepsize $s$, the next level point should be $$(x_0, y_0) + s\,\hat h^\perp$$

Comment: This way I can remain on level; great. If I have two mountain blocks though, and w my goal beyond the second hill with its own contours, how do I switch, how do I know when to switch, from one to the next?

Comment: When a contour circles back on itself, then you are finished with it. For the continuous version, this just means you are back to where you started. In the discrete case, this is harder to determine, since you probably won't land exactly at your starting point. You'll have to establish a "close-enough" criterion, On the other hill, you'll have to move up and down until you establish the same height, then work out its contour.

Answer (score 1):

Level set, fast marching methods methods are used in this context. See

http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1230037/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Perle has some good content here; https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/gpeyre/numerical-tours/blob/master/python/fastmarching_0_implementing.ipynb

I extracted one example for path finding using fast marching,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
from scipy import ndimage

def bilinear_interpolate(im, x, y):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)

    x0 = np.floor(x).astype(int)
    x1 = x0 + 1
    y0 = np.floor(y).astype(int)
    y1 = y0 + 1

    x0 = np.clip(x0, 0, im.shape[1]-1);
    x1 = np.clip(x1, 0, im.shape[1]-1);
    y0 = np.clip(y0, 0, im.shape[0]-1);
    y1 = np.clip(y1, 0, im.shape[0]-1);

    Ia = im[ y0, x0 ]
    Ib = im[ y1, x0 ]
    Ic = im[ y0, x1 ]
    Id = im[ y1, x1 ]

    wa = (x1-x) * (y1-y)
    wb = (x1-x) * (y-y0)
    wc = (x-x0) * (y1-y)
    wd = (x-x0) * (y-y0)

    return wa*Ia + wb*Ib + wc*Ic + wd*Id

def grad(M, bound="sym", order=1):
    """
        grad - gradient, forward differences

          [gx,gy] = grad(M, options);
        or
          g = grad(M, options);

          options.bound = 'per' or 'sym'
          options.order = 1 (backward differences)
                        = 2 (centered differences)

          Works also for 3D array.
          Assme that the function is evenly sampled with sampling step 1.

          See also: div.

          Copyright (c) Gabriel Peyre
    """    


    # retrieve number of dimensions
    nbdims = np.ndim(M)


    if bound == "sym":  
        nx = np.shape(M)[0]
        if order == 1:
            fx = M[np.hstack((np.arange(1,nx),[nx-1])),:] - M
        else:
            fx = (M[np.hstack((np.arange(1,nx),[nx-1])),:] - M[np.hstack(([0],np.arange(0,nx-1))),:])/2.
            # boundary
            fx[0,:] = M[1,:]-M[0,:]
            fx[nx-1,:] = M[nx-1,:]-M[nx-2,:]

        if nbdims >= 2:
            ny = np.shape(M)[1]
            if order == 1:
                fy = M[:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,ny),[ny-1]))] - M
            else:
                fy = (M[:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,ny),[ny-1]))] - M[:,np.hstack(([0],np.arange(ny-1)))])/2.
                # boundary
                fy[:,0] = M[:,1]-M[:,0]
                fy[:,ny-1] = M[:,ny-1]-M[:,ny-2]

        if nbdims >= 3:
            nz = np.shape(M)[2]
            if order == 1:
                fz = M[:,:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,nz),[nz-1]))] - M
            else:
                fz = (M[:,:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,nz),[nz-1]))] - M[:,:,np.hstack(([0],np.arange(nz-1)))])/2.
                # boundary
                fz[:,:,0] = M[:,:,1]-M[:,:,0]
                fz[:,:,ny-1] = M[:,:,nz-1]-M[:,:,nz-2]            
    else:
        nx = np.shape(M)[0]
        if order == 1:
            fx = M[np.hstack((np.arange(1,nx),[0])),:] - M
        else:
            fx = (M[np.hstack((np.arange(1,nx),[0])),:] - M[np.hstack(([nx-1],np.arange(nx-1))),:])/2.

        if nbdims >= 2:
            ny = np.shape(M)[1]
            if order == 1:
                fy = M[:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,ny),[0]))] - M
            else:
                fy = (M[:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,ny),[0]))] - M[:,np.hstack(([ny-1],np.arange(ny-1)))])/2.

        if nbdims >= 3:
            nz = np.shape(M)[2]
            if order == 1:
                fz = M[:,:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,nz),[0]))] - M
            else:
                fz = (M[:,:,np.hstack((np.arange(1,nz),[0]))] - M[:,:,np.hstack(([nz-1],np.arange(nz-1)))])/2.   

    if nbdims==2:
        fx = np.concatenate((fx[:,:,np.newaxis],fy[:,:,np.newaxis]), axis=2)
    elif nbdims==3:
        fx = np.concatenate((fx[:,:,:,np.newaxis],fy[:,:,:,np.newaxis],fz[:,:,:,np.newaxis]),axis=3)

    return fx

def imageplot(f, str='', sbpt=[]):
    """
        Use nearest neighbor interpolation for the display.
    """
    if sbpt != []:
        plt.subplot(sbpt[0], sbpt[1], sbpt[2])
    imgplot = plt.imshow(f, interpolation='nearest')
    imgplot.set_cmap('gray')
    plt.axis('off')

def perform_dijstra_fm(W, pstart, niter=np.inf, method='dijstr', bound='sym', svg_rate=10):
    n = W.shape[0]
    neigh = np.array([[1, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0,  1, -1]])

    def symmetrize(x,n):
        if (x<0):
            x = -x;
        elif (x>=n):
            x = 2*(n-1)-x
        return x

    if bound=='per':
        boundary = lambda x: np.mod(x,n)
    else:
        boundary = lambda x: [symmetrize(x[0],n), symmetrize(x[1],n)] # todo

    ind2sub1 = lambda k: [int( (k-np.fmod(k,n))/n ), np.fmod(k,n)]
    sub2ind1 = lambda u: int( u[0]*n + u[1] )
    Neigh = lambda k,i: sub2ind1(boundary(ind2sub1(k) + neigh[:,i]))
    extract   = lambda x,I: x[I]
    extract1d = lambda x,I: extract(x.flatten(),I)

    nstart = pstart.shape[1]
    I = list( np.zeros( (nstart, 1) ) )
    for i in np.arange(0, nstart):
        I[i] = int( sub2ind1(pstart[:,i]) )

    D = np.zeros( (n,n) ) + np.inf # current distance
    for i in np.arange(0, nstart):
        D[pstart[0,i],pstart[1,i]] = 0

    S = np.zeros( (n,n) )
    for i in np.arange(0, nstart):
        S[pstart[0,i],pstart[1,i]] = 1 # open

    iter = 0
    q = 100  # maximum number of saves
    Dsvg = np.zeros( (n,n,q) )
    Ssvg = np.zeros( (n,n,q) )
    while ( not(I==[]) & (iter<=niter) ):
        iter = iter+1;
        if iter==niter:
            break
        j = np.argsort( extract1d(D,I)  )
        if np.ndim(j)==0:
            j = [j]
        j = j[0]
        i = I[j]
        a = I.pop(j)
        u = ind2sub1(i);
        S[u[0],u[1]] = -1
        J = []
        for k in np.arange(0,4):
            j = Neigh(i,k)
            if extract1d(S,j)!=-1:
                J.append(j)
                if extract1d(S,j)==0:
                    u = ind2sub1(j)
                    S[u[0],u[1]] = 1
                    I.append(j)
        DNeigh = lambda D,k: extract1d(D,Neigh(j,k))
        for j in J:
            dx = min(DNeigh(D,0), DNeigh(D,1))
            dy = min(DNeigh(D,2), DNeigh(D,3))
            u = ind2sub1(j)
            w = extract1d(W,j);
            if method=='dijstr':
                D[u[0],u[1]] = min(dx + w, dy + w)
            else:
                Delta = 2*w - (dx-dy)**2
                if (Delta>=0):
                    D[u[0],u[1]] = (dx + dy + np.sqrt(Delta))/ 2
                else:
                    D[u[0],u[1]] = min(dx + w, dy + w)
        t = iter/svg_rate
        if (np.mod(iter,svg_rate)==0) & (t<q):
            print (t)
            Dsvg[:,:,int(t-1)] = D
            Ssvg[:,:,int(t-1)] = S

    Dsvg = Dsvg[:,:,:int(t-1)]
    Ssvg = Ssvg[:,:,:int(t-1)]
    return (D,Dsvg,Ssvg);

def exo3(x0,W):
    """
    Compute the distance map to these starting point using the FM algorithm.
    """
    n = W.shape[0]
    pstart = transpose(array([x0]))
    [D,Dsvg,Ssvg] = perform_dijstra_fm(W, pstart, inf,'fm', 'sym',n*6)
    # display
    k = 8
    displ = lambda D: cos(2*pi*k*D/ max(D.flatten()))
    plt.figure()
    imageplot(displ(D))
    plt.set_cmap('jet')
    plt.savefig('out-560.png')
    return D


def exo4(tau,x0,x1,G):
    """
    Perform the full geodesic path extraction by iterating the gradient
    descent. You must be very careful when the path become close to
    $x_0$, because the distance function is not differentiable at this
    point. You must stop the iteration when the path is close to $x_0$.
    """
    n = G.shape[0]
    Geval = lambda G,x: bilinear_interpolate(G[:,:,0], imag(x), real(x) ) + 1j * bilinear_interpolate(G[:,:,1],imag(x), real(x))
    niter = 1.5*n/tau;
    # init gamma
    gamma = [x1]
    xtgt = x0[0] + 1j*x0[1]
    for i in arange(0,niter):
        g = Geval(G, gamma[-1] )
        gamma.append( gamma[-1] - tau*g )
        if abs(gamma[-1]-xtgt)<1:
            break
    gamma.append( xtgt )
    return gamma


n = 100
x = linspace(-1, 1, n)
[Y, X] = meshgrid(x, x)
sigma = .2
W = 1 + 8 * exp(-(X**2 + Y**2)/ (2*sigma**2))
x0 = [round(.1*n), round(.1*n)]
D = exo3(x0,W)

G0 = grad(D)
d = sqrt(sum(G0**2, axis=2))
U = zeros((n,n,2))
U[:,:,0] = d
U[:,:,1] = d
G = G0 / U
tau = .8
x1 = round(.9*n) + 1j*round(.88*n)
gamma = [x1]

Geval = lambda G,x: bilinear_interpolate(G[:,:,0], imag(x), real(x) ) + 1j * bilinear_interpolate(G[:,:,1],imag(x), real(x))
g = Geval(G, gamma[-1] )
gamma.append( gamma[-1] - tau*g )
gamma = exo4(tau,x0,x1,G)

imageplot(W) 
plt.set_cmap('gray')
h = plt.plot(imag(gamma), real(gamma), '.b', linewidth=2)
h = plt.plot(x0[1], x0[0], '.r', markersize=20)
h = plt.plot(imag(x1), real(x1), '.g', markersize=20)
plt.savefig('out-760.png')
```